# Getting Warning C6385 if try to use function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, c++-cli, warnings

I get this warning if I try to use function geti() in the following code.

```
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'snapPts':  the readable size is '((geti()+1))*sizeof(DPoint3d)' bytes, but '48' bytes may be read.
```

But If I use integer like

```
int i
```

directly then I am not able to get the warning. I am unable to understand the scenario that what’s happening there, I googled it much but couldn’t find the solution. I am new to c++, please pardon me for spell mistake and please help me to understand this.

Note: I am building the code with "Microsoft Mixed(C++/CLR) Recommended Rules.

I am using the following code

```
#include <windows.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <malloc.h>
#include <corecrt_wstring.h>

int geti() {
return 2;
}
struct  DPoint3d
{
//! x coordinate
double x;
//! y coordinate
double y;
//! z coordinate
double z;
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

int i = 2;


if (i > 1) {

    DPoint3d*   snapPts = (DPoint3d *)_alloca((geti() + 1) * sizeof(DPoint3d));

    DPoint3d* snapPts2 = new DPoint3d();

    *snapPts2 = snapPts[1];


}

return 0;
}
```

A great answer is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message comes out of Visual Studio's static code analyzer, not the compiler. The analyzer is relatively new and does not work very well - it shows a lot of false positives. In your case, it simply did not notice that `geti()` always returns 2.

The real problem in your code is that `*snapPts2 = snapPts[1];` uses uninitialized memory. This is because `_alloca` allocates memory from the stack, but does not initialize it.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene, I just wanna confirm about the analyzer, yes you might be right that it is showing it false positive as it is considering that function can return 0, because if it would return 0 then we would be able to allocate memory of 24 bytes only for the DPoint3d. for the initialization we can say like     snapPts[1] =*snapPts2 ;